# How to create Backbone View in a separate js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to understand how to modularize the Backbone [ToDo tutorial](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html)

Originally everything is inside the same file, but if I try to extract to another file:

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
});
```

then this throws an error:

```
var view = new TodoView({model: todo});

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**
```

It's probably due to a scope issue, but I don't know how to create a reference inside the `$(function()` so I can create this new object inside the main function.

Comment: Can you post your html. Did you include the view js file after moving it into a seperate file?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a module system (it's being introduced with ES6 though) so pretty much all solutions to modularization boils down to either putting stuff in the global scope or using frameworks like browserify or require.js.

Comment: yes the file is included in the html between `<head>` tags before calling the main js file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was to **move the script references to the end of the body** instead of inside the head tags.

I think that the reason is that `TodoView.js` is making use of `templates` that were defined in the body, and since the js file was being loaded before the body, the templates were not yet available.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your first code part is TodoView.js,
and your second code part is app.js.

Write your html file like this,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TodoView.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        // your dom
    </body>
</html>
```

---

(Edited, at 2015-07-27)

sorry for my late reply.
how about this?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!-- your dom -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TodoView.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In many case, most javascript codes are appended to just before `</body>`, so that javascript can use your dom!

Comment: But i recommend to use the module managing library like requirejs.

Comment: It is already like this, but doesn't work... I'm going to try using requirejs

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like require.js to load your external files and manage dependancies.